# Apache 2.2.2 response on HEAD requests

Tags: php, apache, http, http-head

Seems that Apache insists on removing the "Content-Length" header when sending a response to a HEAD request.

Is there a way to configure it (or code it in PHP) to send "Content-Length: 0" for such responses?

For some weird reason it breaks the client (which is not under my control).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look at would be `mod_filter` config. Look in `modules/http/http_filters`. Apache sends `Content-Length` by default, your host or environment may have disabled.

You might have better luck with this over at [`serverfault`](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Here's an answer at SF that might be fruitful: http://serverfault.com/questions/183843/content-length-not-sent-when-gzip-compression-enabled-in-apache

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this one. In my case according the HTTP 1.1, apache is correct and sending the content-length is not a MUST. However, even if I do send it in my code, apache removes it, and this is what I would like to change.

Comment: If your code is sending massive amounts of data, Apache is chunking it in response and therefore wouldn't include content-length.

Comment: I was talking about a response to a HEAD request, which has no content at all.