# PHP response to HEAD request

Tags: php, http, litespeed

I have a PHP script that serves portions of a PDF file by byte ranges.

If an HTTP HEAD request is received, it should send back headers (including the PDF file size) but not the actual file contents. I have tried this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($Pathname));
die;
```

The problem is that something (I assume the web server == LiteSpeed) replaces the Content-Length header with `Content-Length: 0` - which defeats the whole purpose.

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the `$Pathname` is correct?

Comment: How do you know it is replaced?

Comment: @Paul yes the $Pathname variable is definitely correct. I've also written to a log file that confirms that filesize($Pathname) is the actual file size.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - by viewing network activity in Firefox (F12).

Comment: try to add header('Dummy-Length: ' . filesize($Pathname)); and  header('Dummy-Exists: ' . file_exists($Pathname));

Comment: Tried that @IuriiDrozdov - Firefox toolbox reports `Dummy-Length: 1545019` and `Dummy-Exists: 1` (but also `Content-Length: 0`)

Comment: please, specify in your question which webserver are you using, and also the head request made

Comment: @leo_ap The server is LiteSpeed. There is no actual HEAD request sent; for testing, I've coded the PHP to assume it's a HEAD request if a byte-range is not requested.

Comment: I have no idea of LiteSpeed but `Content-Length` tends to be mangled when you have some sort of transparent compression. You should also test a real HEAD request because otherwise you're trying to send incorrect data and the unexpected can happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From w3c Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is
>   allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in
>   the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an
>   invalid length is received and detected.

And:

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

So, I suppose, your code will properly work if you send real HEAD request to your server.

Comment: I can't see that a real HEAD request would make any difference, since the PHP response is independent of the inital request isn't it?

Comment: "I can't see that a real HEAD request would make any difference" - I can. That firmly places the blame at the door of the webserver rather than on PHP or your code (assuming you get the same behaviour in response to a HEAD request).

Comment: @oomp just give it a try. You can use curl -i -D -I -X HEAD http:// yourserver.com (without space between http:// and domain name) or Postman

Comment: Thanks - and to @symcbean - you are right. Who would have believed that in order to respond to a HEAD request, you need a HEAD request? I feel a bit silly now.

Answer (score 2):

It's the webserver job, not yours.

In my case I left everything to the Apache webserver and nothing changed in my php code except of how the requests is being parsed

For example things like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET"){
     //ok
}else{
     //send 400 Bad Request
}
```

are changed to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "HEAD"){
     //ok
}else{
     //send 400 Bad Request
}
```

and Apache did all the heavy lifting (striped the response body).

*(don't try to `ob_clean()` or `die("")` or things like this).*

**related resources:**

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62811/should-i-disable-http-head-requests

[Apache 2.2.2 response on HEAD requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574062/apache-2-2-2-response-on-head-requests)

Answer (score 0):

As Lurii mentioned, the content length is affected by your request type.

With GET requests, a non-matching content length may result in a hanging client, so LiteSpeed will verify the content length before sending the header to the client.

Using a HEAD request should return the content length as expected.